# Dynamics 365: ODataUnrecognizedPathException - Resource Not Found for URL Segment

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I'm encountering an error in Dynamics 365 that states: "URL was not parsed due to an ODataUnrecognizedPathException. Resource not found for the segment provided in the URL." This error occurs when attempting to forward an email within the 'Note and Interaction' tab of a contact module.

Interestingly, I found that forwarding the same email from the email messages module in Dynamics 365 works perfectly without any errors. Upon closer inspection, I noticed a discrepancy in the payload for the request between these two scenarios.

In the problematic scenario, I have an object for email_activity_parties with three items, where the third item contains an 'undefined' text as shown below:

```json
[
    {
        "partyid_systemuser@odata.bind": "systemusers(C74B3097-BDD3-E511-80EF-3863BB358C80)",
        "participationtypemask": 9
    },
    {
        "partyid_systemuser@odata.bind": "systemusers(C74B3097-BDD3-E511-80EF-3863BB358C80)",
        "participationtypemask": 1
    },
    {
        "participationtypemask": 13,
        "partyid_senior_member@odata.bind": "undefined(38FEE338-E2DF-E511-8101-1458D043B558)"
    }
]
```

In the second, working scenario, the email_activity_parties object contains only two items as described below:

```json
[
    {
        "partyid_systemuser@odata.bind": "systemusers(C74B3097-BDD3-E511-80EF-3863BB358C80)",
        "participationtypemask": 9
    },
    {
        "partyid_systemuser@odata.bind": "systemusers(C74B3097-BDD3-E511-80EF-3863BB358C80)",
        "participationtypemask": 1
    }
]
```

I need assistance in resolving this error.

To address this, I've explored various solutions, one of which involves adjusting security roles within the 'Core Records' section.

Specifically, I've granted the following permissions to the tables involved in email management:

**Activity** -Create
Read
Write
Append
Append To

**Email Signature** - Create
Read
Write
Append
Append To

**Email Template** - Create
Read
Write
Append
Append To

**Note** - Create
Read
Write
Append
Append To

Despite implementing these permissions, the email forwarding error still persists. I would greatly appreciate any insights or alternative solutions to resolve this issue effectively.